# Need help showing that $\zeta (x)$= ${1\over 1-2^{1-x}}$ $\eta (x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, euler-product

This question is I am working on is the extension of the domain of zeta function.
$\zeta(x)$=$1+\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{1}{3^x}+\frac{1}{4^x}+\frac{1}{5^x}+\frac{1}{6^x}+ \cdots$
$\eta(x)$=$1-\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{1}{3^x}-\frac{1}{4^x}+\frac{1}{5^x}-\frac{1}{6^x}+ \cdots$
Note: The zeta $\zeta(x)$ function consists of positive terms only and the eta $\eta(x)$ function converges for all positive values for $x$ even when $x$ is less than $0$ where $0\lt x \lt 1$. Also in the equation
 $\zeta (x)$= ${1\over 1-2^{1-x}}$ $\eta (x)$, the left hand side is only defined when $x\gt 1$ because that is the domain of the zeta series. The right hand side can be used to define the zeta function for $0\lt x \lt 1$ and the right hand side totally depends on $\eta(x)$ in the function because it is already defined for all positive values for $x$. 
Here is my attempt so far:
$({1\over 1-2^{1-x}})$ $\eta (x)$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad=({1\over 1-2^{1-x}})\cdot 1 -({1\over 1-2^{1-x}})(\frac{1}{2^x})+({1\over 1-2^{1-x}})(\frac{1}{3^x})-({1\over 1-2^{1-x}})(\frac{1}{4^x})+({1\over 1-2^{1-x}})(\frac{1}{5^x})-({1\over 1-2^{1-x}})(\frac{1}{6^x})+\cdots$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad=(\frac{2^x}{2^x-2})-(\frac{1}{2^x-2})$$+$[$({2/3})^{x}\over{2^x-2}$]$-$($2^{-x}\over{2^x-2}$)$+$[$({2/5})^{x}\over{2^x-2}$]$-$($3^{-x}\over{2^x-2}$)$+\cdots$
By adding each pair of terms from above we get(note: I attempted to input the info but its too difficult to do due to the complexity from combining the terms but I have the next step written down and after that I am stuck showing it). Need help showing that $\zeta (x)$= ${1\over 1-2^{1-x}}$ $\eta (x)$. Getting cancellations is hard

Comment: Hint: try to calculate $\zeta (x) - \eta (x)$.

Comment: @Matt53 how? The $\eta(x)$ is being multiplied on the other side of the equation

Comment: $\zeta (x) - \eta (x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x} - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n^x} - \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x})=2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^x}=2^{1-x}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}=2^{1-x}\zeta (x) $

Answer (score 2):

An idea for you to develop:

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^s}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^s}=\frac1{2^s}\zeta(s)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^s}\implies\ldots$$

Observe you're going to get lots of "poles"...which in fact are removable singularities.

Comment: the problem with this is that on this domain, we do not have any zeroes at all so all values for $x$ must be greater than $1$ . The zeta series diverges at the pole when $x=1$. Are you implying that at those poles, cancellations happen?

Comment: @DDP Of course you have zeros when you continue: $$\zeta(s)=\frac1{2^s}\zeta(s)+...\implies\left(1-\frac1{2^s}\right)\zeta(s)=\ldots$$and etc.

Comment: Are you using an infinite product which can be thought of as a limit to solve it? I used an infinite product using a limit when $x=2$ and I came up with something nice. Im basically showing a zeta series being equal to an alternate harmonic series

Comment: @DDP Some care is needed here: the zeta function equals an alternating series (namely, Eta) **only when** $\;0<x<1\;$ ( or its real part, if you're using a complex argument ). Otherwise the infinite, "usual" sum is what defines it (as above) . I didn't use the usual Euler product over the primes to deduce what I wrote in my answer but merely some basic arithmetic of converging series...

Comment: I see and I have to use $0 \lt x \lt 1$ to show it because in my note section, it says that interval defines the zeta function on the left hand side

Comment: When $x=1$, the denominator in my problem will be $0$ and we already know that the zeta function has a vertical asymptote at $x=1$ which is the poles you were referring to

Comment: @DDP No, I mean the poles in the expression $\;\frac1{1-2^{1-s}}\;$ , as in your question. But this is *only* in case $\;x\in\Bbb C\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

As i said in comment:
$\zeta (x) - \eta (x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x} - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n^x} - \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x})=2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^x}=2^{1-x}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}=2^{1-x}\zeta (x) $

Hence: $\zeta (x)(1 - 2^{1-x}) - \eta(x)=0\\
\zeta(x)=\frac{\eta(x)}{1-2^{1-x}}$

Comment: The only problem I am having is based on the definition on zeta series, $\zeta(x)$ is always greater than $1$ from what I am reading about. I see you came up with $0$ so my question to you is, are you using an infinite product which can be thought of as a limit?

Comment: From what you say I guess you mean $\;\Bbb R\ni x>1\;$ and thus $\;\zeta(x)>1\;$ , but if you want to extend this domain of zeta to $\;(0,1)\;$  (I supposed this is what you wanted to do with the Eta Function...) then it' s values are far from being greater than $1$ ...

Comment: In my note section, its says i have to define the zeta series using the Eta series on the interval $0 \lt x \lt 1$

Comment: @Matt after going over your answer this morning again, the step where the summation next to the parenthesis, how did you pull that 2 out and get $(2n)^x$ in the denominator again?

Comment: @DPP $\frac{1}{n^x}-\frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}}{n^x}=\frac{1-(-1)^{(n-1)}}{n^x}$ would be equal $\frac{2}{n^x}$ or $0$ depending on $n$. For odd $n$ it would be $0$, so sum would be like $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(2n)^x}.$